# DolphinDB: how to divide time period based on given conditions?

Tags: quantitative-finance, dolphindb

Suppose the given stock data are in 1-minute intervals. I’m trying to perform a time split for around every 1.5 million shares traded for each stock so as to obtain data records with different time windows. In this case, around every 1.5 million means that the value at a time point should be added if the sum_volume could be closer to 1.5 million after adding it. Otherwise, the value should not be added.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by the following script. The key to group data lies in the expression: iif(accumulate(caclCumVol{1500000}, volume) ==volume, time, NULL).ffill()

```py
//Define an accumulate function `calcCumVol`. If the value at this point should be included in the current group, the function returns the accumulated volume. Otherwise, it creates a new group and returns the volume at the current point. 

def caclCumVol(target, a, b){
 newVal = a + b
 if(newVal < target) return newVal
 else if(newVal - target > target - a) return b
 else return newVal
}

// import data
t = loadText("f:/DolphinDB/sample.csv")

// The key lies in the the expression iif(accumulate(caclCumVol{1500000), volume) == volume, time, NULL).ffill()

// If the accumulated value == volume, it means a new group begins.

// If it is the start of a new group, record the current time. Otherwise leave it NULL and fill it with function `ffill`. Therefore, the data in the same group all use the same start time.

output = select first(wind_code) as wind_code, first(date) as date, sum(volume) as sum_volume, last(time) as endTime from t group by iif(accumulate(caclCumVol{1500000}, volume) ==volume, time, NULL).ffill() as startTime
```